# Div entrando em outra

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma div com uma imagem, e umas informações dentro dela, a imagem é responsiva e vai aumentando de acordo do tamanho da interface:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" align="center" style="margin-top:50px;  height:20%;  max-height:40%; ">
    <img src="../img/1.png" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:40%;" />

        <table id="table"  >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td  width="22%" align="left"> <a href="#" class="font01" style="margin-left:20%">Cliente</a></li></td>
                    <td  width="20%" align="center"> <a href="#" class="font01" style="margin-left:-50%">Itens</a></li></td>
                    <td  width="20%" align="center"> <a href="#" class="font01">Pagamento</a></li></td>
                    <td  width="20%" align="center"> <a href="#" class="font01">Transporte</a></li></td>
                    <td  width="20%" align="right">  <a href="#" class="font01" style="margin-right:15%">Finalizar</a></li></td>       
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table> 
</div>
```

Botão:

```
<div id="link-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-default"  style="width:50%;  font-size:11px; position:relative; max-width:50% "  aling="center" href="../pages/listarClientes.aspx">Adicionar Cliente</a>
    </div>
```

Problema é que ao ir aumentando o tamanho da tela, a imagem vai descendo e o botão subindo , e o botão fica dentro.

Comment: O problema é que o botão fica em cima da imagem ao redimensionar e não deveria? Ficou um pouco confuso... Essa div do botão fica aonde exatamente? Dentro da outra div ou fora?

Comment: fica fora, o botão é pra ficar sempre abaixo.

Comment: o problema é exatamente isso que vc disse.

Comment: Desculpa, mas não consegui reproduzir seu problema. Poderia tentar criar uma demonstração desse erro em: http://www.bootply.com/new ou https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Poderia postar o HTML como um todo ao invés de separado em pedaços... dessa forma que está não dá pra saber como os dois trechos se relacionam.

Comment: Coloca a classe `clearfix` na div pai, acredito que vai resolver.

Comment: melhorou, mas se maximizar a pagina toda, o botão ainda fica em cima da imagem.